# Saving to XML from AS3 (for eventual use with iOS)

Tags: ios, xml, actionscript-3

I'm an apprentice junior programmer and have been given a project at work, its a simple app in which images are flashed on the screen for a short period of time (starting at 2 seconds) the user has to play for 3 minutes 70% of the images must be clicked / tapped and 30% must be ignored, at the end it displays how many "fails" and how many "halftimes" you got (fails being how many times you clicked an image you WASNT meant to or didnt click an image you WAS meant to and halftimes being how many images you was meant to click that you clicked in half the allotted time i.e at first, if you clicked within 1 second that would count as a halftime click) anyway, all of this works fine, the problem i have is that: i wish to read a value from an XML file (at first the value being 2000 so i can use it as a variable for when i initiate my image timer) which i have achieved, at the END of the game, if the number of fails is 1 or less, i would like to decrease that value by 50 (0.05 seconds) and if the fails is 2 or more i would like to increase the value by 100 (0.1 seconds) and i dont have a clue how i can modify the XML file to change this value, as i said im a junior programmer and dont have much knowledge of AS3 with XML so any help is welcome and appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain all the ins and outs but I can give you some direction. If you're publishing a swf for the web, you will need a server-side script (something like PHP or ASP.net) which can write the change to either a database or an xml file.

If you're publishing a swf or projector for desktop playback, you can combine the ByteArray and FileReference classes to save a file, but a "save as.." dialog will open for the user.

If you're publishing as an AIR application, you can use the File class to modify the xml file.

Hope this helps..